# How can I locate and remove a lingering odor?

Tags: carpet, smell

My parents have a stench in their room and we can not identify it.
It smells fishy.  We have already tried changing the bed sheets, smelling the carpet, etc.  They are clean I know that.

What is the problem and what can I do?

Comment: I am reminded of the [famous Seinfeld episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smelly_Car)... :)

Comment: Sorry for the smell, but is this really on-topic for this home improvement site?

Comment: I don't smell anything. Some problems aren't well suited for resolving over the internet.

Answer (score 3):

It Could be a dead mouse in the wall, it happens sometimes.

Is that the only room that the smell is in?

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  It could be a dead animal of some sort.  (ie; Mouse, Rat, Hamster, Possum, Neighbors cat, bat, bird.)

Does anyone in the family have any small animals or are their outside openings where an animal or bird could get into the walls or attic?

Or it could be a nearly invisible pet mess.  A watery throw-up from a house cat?

Have you crawled around on the floor to see/smell if it is stronger by the floor, walls or ceiling?

Comment: I think this would be more suited as a comment rather than an answer..